# shell command in groovy

Tags: bash, groovy

How to run this command in groovy :

```
/home/srinath/junk/sync.sh > /home/srinath/junk/copy.log
```

This is working when tried on terminal . but fails when used execute in groovy

Could any one please help me on this .

thanks in advance
sri..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shell based redirection and piping doesn't work from inside the JVM without a bit of data handling

For this example, you should be able to do:

```
new File( '/home/srinath/junk/copy.log' ).write( '/home/srinath/junk/sync.sh'.execute().text )
```

Comment: hi tim,  when executed i was getting this issue Caught: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method execute() on null object
 at test.run(test.groovy:11). any thing going wrong ?. thanks

Comment: you can't be running that line of code... no way can that be null as far as I can see